# OneToMany relationship NULL as the foreign key?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosrestbundle

## Preamble

---

I'm trying to POST (*insert in a Postgresql database*) a JSON formatted entity converted into a PHP object thanks to a [FOSRestBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html) route with [JMSSerializerBundle](https://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle). This entity looks like this:

```
**Vote** : OneToOne Bidirectional : **Question** : OneToMany Bidirectional : Answer
```

---

The JSON payload here :

```
{
  "title": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "question": {
    "id": 0,
    "title": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "answers": [
      {
        "title": "string",
        "description": "string"
      },
      {
        "title": "First answer ?",
        "description": "string"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Problem

---

When it inserts the vote, the `vote_id` in the question field is null as well as the `question_id` in answers.

When I get the payload from my route it get transformed into an object with the `fos_rest.request_body` here is the action :

```
    public function postVoteAction(Vote $vote, ConstraintViolationList $violations)
    {
        if (count($violations)) {
            return $this->view($violations, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $vote->setOwner($this->getUser());
        $em->persist($vote);
        $em->flush();
        return $vote;
    }
```

I do get a Vote object with my question and answers but when it get inserted in the database as said earlier foreign key fields are NULL.

### What I have already done

---

I looked into relations & looked if persist was there in entities `cascade={"persist"}`

```
// in vote
@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Question", mappedBy="vote", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
private $question;

// in question
@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Vote", inversedBy="question", cascade={"persist"})
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="vote_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private $vote;

@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="question", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
private $answers;

// in answer
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="answers", cascade={"persist"})
@ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private $question;
```

I used `php bin\console make:entity --regenerate` to get all
   getters/setters. 
I cleared the database & regenerated it.

### Answer

---

As said by @yTko I forgot to put the references back to my object in my controller I thought that it was made by Doctrine with the persist so here is now my working code :

```
public function postVoteAction(Vote $vote, ConstraintViolationList $violations)
{
    if (count($violations)) {
        return $this->view($violations, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $vote->setOwner($this->getUser());
    $question = $vote->getQuestion();
    $question->setVote($vote);
    foreach ($question->getAnswers() as $answer) {
        $answer->setQuestion($question);
    }
    $em->persist($vote);
    $em->flush();

    return $vote;
}
```

Comment: Far to much code for anyone to crawl through. Please reduce it to a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include the code in your question.

Comment: Show us the annotations defining the relations between the entities, please.

Comment: @Zak added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you've just forgotten to set related instances of vote and questions.

In your controller action you have the vote object that converted by jms with from your json example.

So, you need to set them manually through calling certain setters, like this:

```
$question = $vote->getQuestion();
$question->setVote($vote);
```

or modify your setters this way:

```
public function setQuestion(Question $question)
{
    $this->question = $question;
    $this->question->setVote($this);

    return $this;
}
```

I prefer the first way because setters is just for setting concrete values, not for modifying other objects.

Comment: So I'll have to do that for my answers too ?

Comment: Yep, for all of your nestings. because jms just mapped json on entity objects and thats all. also, you can try https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#postdeserialize method and set your relations in there but i not recommend to use it like any other magic if you doesn't have wand